# Firestore FieldValue is always undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am always getting an error from the FieldValue method that it is undefined. Anybody any ideas? I am using react...

```
   function incrementLikes() {
    firebase.db
      .collection('projects')
      .doc(data.id)
      .update({ likes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });
  }


<LikeButton likesCount={data.likes} onClick={incrementLikes} />
```

Comment: `FieldValue` was in the SDK pretty early, so it's unlikely to be a version issue. It would really help to see the exact error message. But it'd also be useful to see how you import `firebase`, as `firebase.db` seems not the standard JavaScript SDK import.